# What will happen if I won`t complete a maintenance module?

Tags: trailhead, certification, certificates

Right now I have a **Platform Developer I Certificate**. But I am not working with the Salesforce right now and do not plan to work with it in the near future. So, from my perspective it seems redundant to spend time on the module, but at the same time I would like to preserve my certificate.

So, is it possible to complete all the maintenance modules later in the future when I will be working with the Salesforce and preserve the certificate in this way?

I think I will need to recap all the modules anyway so, it will be a good way for me to do that, while if I will learn them now I will just forget all that I learned.

Comment: Honestly, the maintenance modules are really easy. It will take 15 minutes. I would just get on with it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in the [Certification Expiration Overview](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help?article=Information-about-Certification-Expiration).

Generally speaking, you will lose the certification **and** any other dependent certifications. E.g. if you expire an Administrator cert due to missing the maintenance exam you will also expire the Advanced Administrator exam.

There are currently a few exceptions listed to this where you have a grace period to re-certify on an expired dependent cert. At the time of writing, that included Platform Developer II and the Application/System architecture certs.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not do the required maintenance your certification will expire and you will have to retake the exam when you are ready to earn it back.